# Update One xml with another using C# and xdocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to update one xml file with another using C#.
The documents have the same schema but the updating document has new odds, new events new sports. I'm comparing the two files using ID's, but for tournament I must compare them by names. Sometimes there are updated odds and I need to replace them from the file for update with those which are in the updating document

**This is the file for update**

```
<Sports>
    <Sport id="5" name="Tennis">
        <Tournament id="3" name="ATP - Basel, Switzerland">
            <Match id="8331220" name="Federer, Roger v Sock, Jack" startDate="2015-10-31T14:50:00">
                <MatchOdds>
                    <Bet id="20">
                        <Outcome Special="" name="1" odds="1.1"/>
                        <Outcome Special="" name="2" odds="8.25"/>
                    </Bet>
                    <Bet id="231">
                        <Outcome Special="" name="1" odds="1.22"/>
                        <Outcome Special="" name="2" odds="4.5"/>
                    </Bet>
                </MatchOdds>
            </Match>
        </Tournament>
    </Sport>
</Sports>
```

**This is sample updating file**

```
<Sports>
    <Sport id="5" name="Tennis">
        <Tournament id="3" name="ATP - Basel, Switzerland">
            <Match id="8331220" name="Federer, Roger v Sock, Jack" startDate="2015-10-31T14:50:00">
                <MatchOdds>
                    <Bet id="20">
                        <Outcome Special="" name="1" odds="34"/>
                        <Outcome Special="" name="2" odds="34"/>
                    </Bet>
                    <Bet id="231">
                        <Outcome Special="" name="1" odds="34"/>
                        <Outcome Special="" name="2" odds="3434"/>
                    </Bet>
                    <Bet id="233">
                        <Outcome Special="" name="2:0" odds="1.35"/>
                        <Outcome Special="" name="2:1" odds="3.8"/>
                        <Outcome Special="" name="0:2" odds="16.25"/>
                        <Outcome Special="" name="1:2" odds="12.75"/>
                    </Bet>

                </MatchOdds>
            </Match>
            <Match id="8331268" name="Peya A / Soares B v Rojer J-J / Tecau H" startDate="2015-10-31T16:10:00">
                <MatchOdds>
                    <Bet id="20">
                        <Outcome Special="" name="1" odds="2.15"/>
                        <Outcome Special="" name="2" odds="1.75"/>
                    </Bet>

                </MatchOdds>
            </Match>
            <
    <Sport id="23" name="Volleyball">
        <Tournament id="195" name="Turkey - 1. Lig, Women">
            <Match id="8155390" name="Idmanocagi v Halkbank Ankara" startDate="2015-10-31T14:00:00">
                <MatchOdds>
                    <Bet id="226">
                        <Outcome Special="178.5" name="Over" odds="1.8"/>
                        <Outcome Special="178.5" name="Under" odds="1.95"/>
                    </Bet>
                </MatchOdds>
            </Match>

        </Tournament>
    </Sport>

</Sports>
```

**The result xml file must be like this one:**

```
<Sports>
    <Sport id="5" name="Tennis">
        <Tournament id="3" name="ATP - Basel, Switzerland">
            <Match id="8331220" name="Federer, Roger v Sock, Jack" startDate="2015-10-31T14:50:00">
                <MatchOdds>
                    <Bet id="20">
                        <Outcome Special="" name="1" odds="1.1"/>
                        <Outcome Special="" name="2" odds="8.25"/>
                    </Bet>
                    <Bet id="231">
                        <Outcome Special="" name="1" odds="34"/>
                        <Outcome Special="" name="2" odds="3434"/>
                    </Bet>
                    <Bet id="233">
                        <Outcome Special="" name="2:0" odds="1.35"/>
                        <Outcome Special="" name="2:1" odds="3.8"/>
                        <Outcome Special="" name="0:2" odds="16.25"/>
                        <Outcome Special="" name="1:2" odds="12.75"/>
                    </Bet>
                </MatchOdds>
            </Match>
            <Match id="8331268" name="Peya A / Soares B v Rojer J-J / Tecau H" startDate="2015-10-31T16:10:00">
                <MatchOdds>
                    <Bet id="20">
                        <Outcome Special="" name="1" odds="2.15"/>
                        <Outcome Special="" name="2" odds="1.75"/>
                    </Bet>

                </MatchOdds>
            </Match>
        </Tournament>
    </Sport>
    <Sport id="23" name="Volleyball">
        <Tournament id="195" name="Turkey - 1. Lig, Women">
            <Match id="8155390" name="Idmanocagi v Halkbank Ankara" startDate="2015-10-31T14:00:00">
                <MatchOdds>
                    <Bet id="226">
                        <Outcome Special="178.5" name="Over" odds="1.8"/>
                        <Outcome Special="178.5" name="Under" odds="1.95"/>
                    </Bet>
                </MatchOdds>
            </Match>

        </Tournament>
    </Sport>
</Sports>
```

I'm a newcomer to C# and I'm still learning. So I write this code:
https://github.com/cologneto/123456/blob/master/LastTry/MerginXmls.cs

As you can see I can't use LINQ and I wrote it the hard way using XmlDocument and a lots of "for" loops. This makes my code unreadable and some times it works sometime not. That is why I put in the try-catch conditions. 
I'm sure that it can be made in much shorter and clean way.
 Can someone help me to give me direction how to do it with XDocument LINQ?

Georgi

Comment: I would suggest you look into XML Serialization and Deserialization in C# then you can get lists of objects that can be manipulated in a way that is easier to read and maintain

Comment: You wrote: _I need to **replace**_ - but I don't see in the first xml `Sport id="23"` node, so why you **added** this node in the resulting xml? Describe the **exact** update rules.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I'm sorry for the explanation. I will try to edit again and explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

Like suggest you should look into XML Serialization and Deserialization in C# You should try something like this update xml files.

Start with generate a class from the XML Schema (XSD) document, for make easy access to nodes and elements in xmlfiles.

Use the XML Schema Definition Tool xsd.exe found in your framework tools to convert your schema into a serializable class or dataset.

**run (at the vs command prompt)**

```
xsd /c Sports.xsd
```

Add class .cs file was created your project.In project at add this code have do some modifications for example filenames, class and namespace

```
  //Open the two xml files examples
  FileStream file1 = new FileStream(@"c:\New_Result_Tournaments.xml", FileMode.Open);
  FileStream file2 = new FileStream(@"c:\Sports_odds_databas.xml", FileMode.Open);

  // 
  XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(yourNamespace.yourClass));
  try
  {
    myNamespace.yourClass NewResult = ser.Deserialize(file1) as myNamespace.yourClass;
    yourNamespace.yourClass SportOddsDatbas = ser.Deserialize(file2) as myNamespace.yourClass;
    if( NewResult != null && SportOddsDatbas != null)
    {
      /* Here you should have access both xml files just 
         add information want update seconed file with from 
         the first.*/

      // Save the updates made in c:\Sports_odds_databas.xml
      serializer.Serialize(file2, SportOddsDatbas);
    }

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // Todo)
    // Very good to use the exception to find fault mapping of XML can save lot of time.
  }
  file1.Close();
  file2.Close();
```